# Is ICollection<T>.Add ThreadSafe?

Tags: c#, multithreading, list, collections, thread-safety

I have a [BindingList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679.aspx) that I'm gonna populate in two different threads... Is using the [BindingList.Add()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132404.aspx) method ThreadSafe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the `BindingList.Add` method is not thread safe.

In the documentation for the class you can find this standard phrase under thread safety:

> "Any public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are
>   thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread
>   safe."

That means that the class doesn't have any thread safety considerations.

You need to synchronise any accesses to the `BindingList` instance. You can use that with the `lock` keyword:

```
lock(_sync) {
  myBindingList.Add(something);
}
```

The object that the variable `_sync` refers to is used as an identifier for the lock, so all code that accesses that list has to use the same reference for the lock. Usually an object instance is used:

```
private object _sync = new Object();
```

Answer (score 4):

No, `Collection<T>.Add` is not thread safe.

Often MSDN covers thread safety in class article rather than individual methods. I.e. for [Collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132397.aspx)

> A Collection can support **multiple readers concurrently**, as long as the collection is not modified. Even so, enumerating through a collection is intrinsically not a thread-safe procedure. To guarantee thread safety during enumeration, you can lock the collection during the entire enumeration. To allow the collection to be accessed by multiple threads for **reading and writing, you must implement your own synchronization**.

Note that you can't say if interface's method is thread safe or not because interface don't define any thread safety requirements, it only specifies method signature. You need to check each individual implementation if it have any particular guarantees on thread safety.

Answer (score 1):

The System.Collections.Concurrent namespace provides several thread-safe collection classes that should be used in place of the corresponding types in the System.Collections and System.Collections.Generic namespaces whenever multiple threads are accessing the collection concurrently.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.aspx